# Continuous pinching zoom on touchpad with libinput-gestures

Tags: touchpad, libinput

I have an Elantech touchpad, and am working on `i3wm` on Manjaro.

I am using libinput-gestures to define pinching gestures in the following way : (`~/.config/libinput-gestures.conf`)

```
# Zoom View In (Works in quite a few apps: Browser, Files, photos, etc...)
gesture: pinch out xdotool key control+shift+plus
#

# Zoom View Out (Works in quite a few apps: Browser, Files, photos, etc...)
gesture: pinch in xdotool key control+minus
#
```

However this behaves in a discrete way. That is that the zoom is not continuous but incremental on my firefox browser for instance.
Is there a way to configure `libinput-gestures` to pinch-zoom in a continuous way ?

Cheers

Comment: Did you found any solution?

Answer (score 4):

Not a solution based on libinput-gestures, but I founnd that [fusuma](https://github.com/iberianpig/fusuma) has settings for threshold and interval.

Right now my config is like

```
pinch:
  in:
    shortcut: 'ctrl+shift+plus'
  out:
    shortcut: 'ctrl+minus'

threshold:
  swipe: 0.5
  pinch: 0.2

interval:
  swipe: 1 
  pinch: 0.2
```

However the zoom in gesture is hardly detected, I have to use three fingers to make sure it is not locked as a swipe up/down.